# Repeated swap on Uniswap fails with SPL error

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

I was trying to swap WETH to LUSD in my test and for some reason the swap fails with SPL error when I do so multiple times. I thought it's a liquidity issue but swapping large amount at once works fine. Does anybody have any idea why this can be the case?

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.4;

import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import {ISwapRouter} from "../../../interfaces/uniswapv3/ISwapRouter.sol";
import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract SwapTest is Test {
    address public constant LUSD = 0x5f98805A4E8be255a32880FDeC7F6728C6568bA0;
    address public constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    address public constant USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48; // set here because of multihop on Uni

    ISwapRouter public constant UNI_ROUTER = ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

    function testLargeSwap() public {
        address bridge = address(234);

        vm.prank(bridge);
        IERC20(WETH).approve(address(UNI_ROUTER), type(uint256).max);

        deal(WETH, bridge, 10 ether);

        vm.prank(bridge);
        UNI_ROUTER.exactInput(
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams({
                path: abi.encodePacked(WETH, uint24(500), USDC, uint24(500), LUSD),
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: 10 ether,
                amountOutMinimum: 0
            })
        );
    }

    function testRepeatedSwap() public {
        address bridge = address(234);

        vm.prank(bridge);
        IERC20(WETH).approve(address(UNI_ROUTER), type(uint256).max);

        for (uint256 i; i < 5; ++i) {
            deal(WETH, bridge, 1 ether);

            vm.prank(bridge);
            UNI_ROUTER.exactInput(
                ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams({
                    path: abi.encodePacked(WETH, uint24(500), USDC, uint24(500), LUSD),
                    recipient: address(this),
                    deadline: block.timestamp,
                    amountIn: 1 ether,
                    amountOutMinimum: 0
                })
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about the underlying uniswapv3 math to understand why the SPL is getting busted here. I'm guessing there's something about executing multiple one-way swaps in a single transaction that really throws the price limit off.

A workaround that I found to execute multiple swaps is to swap e.g. 1M ether/DAI in one direction, warp forward, and then swap it back. You'd need to basically reverse the path with whatever output amount is given.